# Can a pointer take arguments? What is the difference between these 3 kind of pointers

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I want to know what is the meaning of the following statements.

```
int *abc(int,int);
int (*abc)(int,int);
```

and how these pointers are different from the ordinary pointer. ex:

```
int *ptr;
```

Thank you

Comment: In what programming language?

Comment: @JJJ C or C++ would be appriciated.

Comment: Tagging the question correctly would be appreciated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work

Comment: I'll make sure to do that from very next time. Thanks JJJ..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do function pointers in C work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work)

Answer (score 1):

> Can a pointer take arguments?

No, a pointer is just a variable which stores address of a memory location.

> int *abc(int,int);

This is a declaration of function `abc` which takes two arguments, both of type `int`, and returns a pointer to an `int` type.

> int (*abc)(int,int);

Here, `abc` is a pointer that can point to a function which takes two `int` type arguments and returns an `int`.
Say, if you have a function `fun`:

```
int fun(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

`abc` can point to `fun()`, like this:

```
abc = fun;
```

then you can call function `fun` using `abc` pointer, like this:

```
abc(4, 5);
```

> how these pointers are different from the ordinary pointer. ex:
>   int *ptr;

Here, `ptr` is a pointer which can store the address of an `int` type.

Hence, all the pointers store some memory location, the difference lies in the address of a type they point to.

Answer (score 0):

assuming C/C++
this: `int *abc(int,int);` is a prototype of function returning a pointer to `int` and taking two arguments of type `int`

this: `int (*abc)(int,int);` is a declaration of a pointer to function returning `int` and taking two arguments of type `int`

Comment: `int (*abc)(int,int);` is just a pointer variable, not "prototype" of any kind.